# How to use get_value to get objectName?

Tags: perl, activerecord, ldap

This code

```
my @bl = ();
foreach my $entry ($m->entries) {
  push @bl, "$entry->get_value('objectName', asref => 0)";
}

print Dumper @bl;
```

outputs

```
$VAR1 = 'Net::LDAP::Entry=HASH(0x5c70920)->get_value(\'objectName\', asref => 0)';
$VAR1 = 'Net::LDAP::Entry=HASH(0x5c706c0)->get_value(\'objectName\', asref => 0)';
$VAR1 = 'Net::LDAP::Entry=HASH(0x5c70660)->get_value(\'objectName\', asref => 0)';
```

which I don't understand why it does.

If I change `objectName` to `sAMAccountName`, it gives something meaningful.

If I dump `$m->entries` I see

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'changes' => [],
                 'changetype' => 'modify',
                 'asn' => {
                            'objectName' => 'CN=sandra,OU=list,DC=example,DC=com',
                            'attributes' => []
                          }
               }, 'Net::LDAP::Entry' );
```

How do I get the `objectName` using `get_value()`?

**Update**: First comment solved the problem.

Comment: try this "$entry->{'asn'}->{'objectName'};"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method calls are not interpolated into double-quoted strings.  In this case, it doesn't seem like you need the quotes at all:

```
my @bl = ();
foreach my $entry ($m->entries) {
  push @bl, $entry->get_value('objectName', asref => 0);
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
my @bl = map { $_->get_value('objectName', asref => 0) } $m->entries;
```

Note that Ibrahim's comment is a bad idea.  You should never go poking around inside an object's internals; use the public interface instead.

Comment: Never is a strong word. The author of a public interface does not always anticipate how a user will want to use the code. And besides, poking inside an object's internals is often enlightening and fun.

Comment: @mob: OK, I'll amend my comment to "You should never go poking around inside an object's internals, unless you're deliberately writing fragile code."

Answer (score 1):

FYI `objectName` here is the object's DN. To get/set it you should be using `$entry->dn`